# Gnome and Unity are running at the same time

Tags: unity, gnome

I tried to install gnome3 using a ppa. It made a mess so I reinstalled my system. Now, for some reason, when I enter to the Ubuntu classic session, I get both unity and gnome running at the same time (all my gnome-panels + unity dashboard and menu).

I suppose there is some configuration wrong in my home directory, but I have no idea of what should I change to get only gnome.

Any idea of how can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1)** We will need [Compiz Settings Manager](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager).

You can install this from the *Ubuntu Software Center* or by clicking  [here (Compiz)](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager)

**2)** Open Compiz (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and type `ccsm` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>)

**3)** Go to Unity plugin and disable it.